# SVN Server Not Responding to Write Requests

Tags: ios, apache, svn, config, haproxy

I am in the process of trying to set up an SVN repo using an apache web server. I was able to get the repo created and configured without too many problems. I can reach the repo via the browser, so I think the apache configuration is correct. The problem comes when I try to do the initial commit. When I run the commit command in the terminal, it hangs for several minutes before returning `svn: E175012: Connection timed out`. The initial commit is a single file, less than 100kb. Even more strange, after the command times out, it seems to create an HTTPd process on my system that uses 90% of the CPU.

I did some research to see if I could solve the problem myself, but so far nothing has worked. I was able to use Charles Proxy to monitor the HTTP requests and it looks like the svn client is sending the POST but it is never receiving a response from the server. After the default timeout (10 minutes) the client gives up and displays the timeout error.

I also tried setting up the repo using `SvnServe` instead of apache. I was able to read and write to the repo using svn://. However, the code I am working on expects to communicate with the repo over HTTP, so I still need to figure out what the problem is with apache.

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue? Are there any other steps I can take to troubleshoot the problem for myself?

**[Update]**

I checked the logs for my apache server. Here is what I'm seeing when I run the commit:

`_myip_ - - [28/Feb/2017:10:04:04 -0500] "OPTIONS /my/repo HTTP/1.1" 200 190 "-" "SVN/1.9.5 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0) serf/1.3.9"
_myip_ - - [28/Feb/2017:10:04:04 -0500] "OPTIONS /my/repo HTTP/1.1" 200 97 "-" "SVN/1.9.5 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0) serf/1.3.9"`

**[Update 2]**
In an attempt to further narrow down the cause of this issue, I tried setting up a different apache server in a Linux virtual machine. That server worked perfectly, and I was even able to read/write to it from osx. So it would seem that the issue is something specific to the apache server on OSX.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this.

> $ sudo chmod -R 775 /var/lib/svn

Reference URL-: https://gotechnies.com/setup-svn-server-ubuntu/

Comment: Please consider adding some context to your link (i.e. quoting the relevant part of the article). http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, it works fine in a linux system. It's on OSX where I'm having issues.